# How to find the length of hive json array field using hive query

Tags: arrays, json, hive, hiveql, hive-query

```
"keys": [ "2324", "abc"]
```

This is one of the key of hive JSON. I want to find the length of the `"keys"` field. i am reading the JSON using `get_json_object()` method.

This is the way I am doing but getting error:

```
select count(*) from table_name where json_array_length(get_json_object(node,'$.keys'))=2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are looking into an json array, you could simply do a `split` and then apply `size` to get the desired result.

```
select size(split(get_json_object(data,'$.keys'),',')) from <table name>;
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_json_object` returns string. Remove square brackets and `split` to get array, use `size` to get array size:

```
size(split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(node,'$.keys'),'\\[|\\]',''),'", '))
```